# tableView editing mode delete button (minus sign) not responding to tap - how do I fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When my tableView goes into editing mode there's an icon on each side of my cell: the icon on the right is the default icon for rearranging the order of cells, and the icon on the left is the default icon for deleting a cell. I can easily interact with the rearranging icon with no problems, however, tapping on the delete icon gives no response. It only works when I do an awkward right swipe then left swipe on it. Below I've placed what I believe to be all the relevant code to my situation.

Some background information: I have three touch gestures in the view (a single tap, double tap, and long press). I've tried disabling them with conditions for when the editing mode is enabled. I've even tried deleting the touch gestures beforehand, but that didn't help. I thought it might be an auto layout issue that's not registering the area for the delete button, but the rearranging button works so shouldn't this? Both the my cell's leading and trailing constants are +10 to the view. Furthermore, isEditing is controlled by a UIButton. Finally, i have the tableView delegate set to self, and touch interaction when editing is enabled.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if isEditing { return true }
    return false
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    if isEditing { return .delete }
    return .none
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        countBeforeDeletingCell =  dataSource.data.count
        dataSource.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedObject = dataSource.data[sourceIndexPath.row]
    dataSource.data.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    dataSource.data.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey If the you have use UITableViewController and using isEditing iOS defalut mode you have to override setEditing Mode and Changing Edit button Click.

- iOS `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem` in `editButtonItem` is default `UIViewController` method. `editButtonItem` button Action override.

`Swift` Example:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me on swift 5.7.May be you should config TrailingSwipeActionConfiguration like this:

```
unc tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive,
                                                  title: "Delete") { [weak self] _, _, complete in
                //remove row in you data model here
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                complete(true)
            }
            deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

            return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    }
```